# IntelliJ IDEA not importing maven dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have moved my OneDrive folder where I keep all my Java projects to another drive on my computer.  Now none of my projects will run through Intelliij as the program complains that it can't find any of the Maven dependencies.  Although they are listed in the external project folder and the IDE doesn't underline the imports red in the IDE

I have gotten the project to work by deleting all of the .idea files, using maven to do a clean install and then re-importing the project.  This method doesn't work 100% of the time and when I close and reopen the IDE it will break the project again.

I've made sure that I ticked the "import Maven projects automatically" box but it seems to untick itself in between loads.  The source file will disappear from the project in-between loads, and it will drop the JDK and force me to re import it.

This is what the console looks like.

[image]

EDIT1: I've added the POM file as I've been requested to do so.  Although the POM file isn't the problem as it works in Eclipse

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.20</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7-1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

EDIT 2

I've uploaded some video of the problem it's a bit hard to tell what's going on because I used windows game bar to record them but I cloned this repository with GIT

https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring5-mysql-recipe-app/tree/refactor-db-init

Imported the file and it worked.  Here is a video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeZ2mcJkhBw&feature=youtu.be

I then closed and reset the project and this happened.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huap0feeuuU&feature=youtu.be

Does anyone have a clue what could be happening?

EDIT 3:

I decided to move stuff outside of the OneDrive folder and it seems to work fine.  Although I didn't have this problem when I had my OneDrive folder on the C drive.  Weird.

Comment: What do you mean by dependencies "are listed in the external project folder"? Do you mean that dependencies have scope system - like here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies?

Comment: I mean that I can see all of the maven libraries I need to import in the project toolbar under "external libraries -> Maven: xxx".  My POM file is fine as I get run the app from the command line and Eclipse.  It's some weird setup problem with Intelij.

Comment: Are you sure that you select pom.xml when importing the project into IntelliJ, not just the folder?

Comment: Doesn't make any difference.  Tried both ways.

Comment: Is it the local file system drive or a network mount? Re-importing Maven project actually should help. Check the Maven libraries in the File | Project Structure | Libraries settings - do they each have valid paths for the Classes/Sources?

Comment: I've re-imported the Maven project a bunch of times it doesn't always work.  None of the changes I make seem to persist between loads.

Comment: It's a local file system.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your pom, particularly the top and the `<dependencies>` section

Comment: Done.  As I said before though the application still runs fine inside Eclipse.

Comment: Did you check to make sure that the maven that IJ is using is the same as the one Eclipse is using, and that both are using the same settings?

Comment: There is only one pom file in the directory.  It's happening to all my projects now.  If I close IntelliJ IDEA it loses the connection to the POM file and discards the JDK and I have to reset it.

Comment: Can you navigate to the not found classes via Navigate | Class action?
 Please [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) and provide [project configuration files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-projects.html#project-formats) zipped (`.idea` project configuration sub-folder and module's `.iml` files) and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) after IDE restart and re-importing Maven project in Maven tool window.